# django is there some way to pick up value from ModelForm before it gets validated?

Tags: django, django-forms

Assume these as django models:

```
class Author():

    name = charfield()

class Book():

    title = charfield()
    author = foreignkey()
```

and a `ModelForm`:

```
class BookForm():

    # i override the author field
    author = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('title', 'author')
```

I'm using an autocomplete plugin (like facebook search, so i can fill the author field without using choicefield).The problem is, i cannot assign value from `author` field because it is not an instance of author, it is a string. So i'm thinking to manipulate it before it gets validated. I tried modifying the `QueryDict` but is immutable. As soon as i invoke the form with `form = BookForm(request.POST)` it gets the error : `Cannot assign u"foo":"Book.author" must be an Author instance`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing it the "django way". you need to write your own widget for the author field.

and do something like this:

```
class BookForm():

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('title', 'author')
        widgets = {
        'author': YourFacebookLikeWidgetClass,
    }
```

Now, your widget is responsible for doing all your cool stuff, (ajax call, rendering the results...etc) , but in the end, it will return  the right value for the form. (the author ID)

Read more about [django widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/)

The problem is that there isnt a lot of info about writing your own widgets, but you can always ask here, and watch the source code of some django widgets. (It is not vert complicated to write your own :) )